# How to install Crystal Reports viewer on client machine when client install windows installer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, c#-3.0

I run the same exe file on another computer, but it gives error. The application works on my pc, but does not work on user's pc. I try to compile the app in other development machine and it is work well, the problem is my app doesn't work on user's pc.

> *Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecision.Shared,
>   Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder called Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Crystal Reports\CRRedist\IA64 in your Programs folder. There you will find a redistributable package. Just add this file to your setup project - user defined actions - and install it.

edit: As you mentioned setupProject CustomActions only allows exe/dll files

I found another solution. Hope this ones satisfies your needs.

Add a mergeModul to your setupProject :

(right-click solution explorer on setupProject, add mergeModul).

A folder called C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules should automatically show up. There you may find a file called CrystallReportsRedistxxx.msm.

Add this to your project and it should install too.

[BusinessObjects_CrystallReports](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp)

[MS CrystalReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287924%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[Adding Components to the Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227420%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[How To Create Setup And Deployment Project With Crystal Report In VS Studio 2008](http://www.fryan0911.com/2010/07/how-to-create-setup-and-deployment.html)

Comment: i am not found the CrystalReportRedistxxx on merge module